# Необходимость наследовать AbstractList

Tags: java

У кого-нибудь стояла задача расширения AbstractList или AbstractSet и т.п.? 
Зачем вы это делали, приведите пример, пожалуйста.
Я понимаю, что скелетная конструкция абстрактного класса не слишком абстрактна, но и не слишком зареализована, и в этом преимущество. Но хотелось бы реального примера.
Спасибо.

Comment: Лучшие реальные примеры содержит Collection Framework в JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лично я таким не занимался, но вот хороший пример: класс [`TreeList`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/TreeList.html) из библиотеки Apache Commons. В данном случае класс реализует список, оптимизированный для быстрых операций удаления и вставки элементов. Или класс [`DefaultedMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/map/DefaultedMap.html) оттуда же. Он изменяет логику стандартного `HashMap` таким образом, чтобы при извлечении данных по ключу, которого нет в мапе возвращался не `null`, а какое-нибудь значение по умолчанию. Таким образом, мы видим целых два применения наследованию от классов стандартных коллекций: реализация нестандартных алгоритмов хранения данных, оптимизированных для определённых случаев, или изменение поведения стандартных классов на более удобное.